# How can I add domain names to my terraform configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-registry

I want to Add domain to listener rule in addition to paths. What arguments should I use for the same.

```
resource "aws_alb_listener_rule" "service" {
  listener_arn = var.alb_listener_arn
  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.service.arn
  }
  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = ["/login", "/logout"]
    }
  }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. This worked.

```
condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = ["/login", "/logout"]
    }
}
condition {
    host_header {
      values = ["my-service.*.terraform.io"]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The domain name is specified using [host_header](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb_listener_rule):

> Contains a single values item which is a list of host header patterns to match.

An example usage from the docs:

```
  condition {
    host_header {
      values = ["my-service.*.terraform.io"]
    }
  }
```